# How to enable standard internet services on Mac OS X 10.5?

Tags: macos, mac, networking, internet, osx-leopard

I'd like to access standard internet services as echo (port 7), discard (9), daytime (13), chargen (19) and others on my Mac OS X machine (running Mac OS X Leopard). If possible, how to enable them?

Telnet is rejected on each of those ports on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The services you mentioned were part of **xinetd**, which is not used in Leopard. It was replaced with launchd, and I'm afraid there is no easy way to run those services out of the box.

[Getting started with launchd](http://developer.apple.com/MacOsX/launchd.html) (Apple.com)

[Technical Note TN2083
Daemons and Agents](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2005/tn2083.html#SECANCIENTDAEMONS) (Apple.com)

Answer (score 1):

Linux used to let you turn services on one at a time, e.g. /sbin/chkconfig echo on.  I now use macs to lecture (I want these for introductory programming – networking).  So there's no equiv?